# adding scrpit (function) to image in sheets using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In sheets directly, you can add a GAS funtion to an image.  This creats a feel of a "button" to trigger a script when clicked/pressed.

As I import images into the sheet using GAS, Is there in return a way to add the script to the image using GAS?  I can add a URL, but not seeing a way to tie a script to the image.  Thought id ask here before giving up.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Post some code based on what you did till now. Thanks